# How to prove that $ \lim_{x \to \infty} \frac{1}{x^{2}} = 0 $?

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, limits

Using a $\delta$, $\epsilon$ argument, how does one prove that $ \lim_{x \to \infty} \frac{1}{x^{2}} = 0 $?

Comment: How would you get started? (For limits at infinity you have to find a large $N$ (depending on $\epsilon$), not a $\delta$.)

Comment: This is the limit as x^2 goes to infinity of 1/x^2.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can make $1/x^2$ arbitrarily small, by taking very large $x.$
More precisely, for any given positive $\epsilon,$ $$\dfrac{1}{x^2}\lt \epsilon\iff\dfrac{1}{\sqrt{\epsilon}}\lt x.$$

Answer (score 0):

For $x>1$, we have

$$\frac{1}{x^2}<\frac{1}{x}$$

thus, for given $\epsilon>0$ , take $$A=max(1,\frac{2}{\epsilon}).$$

then

$x>A \; \implies x>1\;$ and$\; x>\frac{2}{\epsilon}$

$$\implies 0<\frac{1}{x^2}<\frac{1}{x}<\frac{\epsilon}{2}<\epsilon.$$

$$\implies \lim_{x\to+\infty}\frac{1}{x^2}=0.$$